# facebook cordova app share images without plugin

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova

Using this link [facebook-phonegap-cordova-without-plugin](http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/04/facebook-phonegap-cordova-without-plugin/)  I create a `cordova Facebook app`. It works well for me, but I can only `share links or text messages`. I can't share images using this method.
Is there any other way to share text + images on facebook **without using a share plugin**. I used the social share plugin but with this method facebook application should be installed on the device.

I even use the facebook javascript SDK :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&   appId=xxxx&version=v2.0";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true">
</div>
```

and added the  meta data:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxx" />
<meta property="og:title"  content="titre" /> 
<meta property="og:image"  content="url-img" /> 
<meta property="og:url"  content="url" /> 
<meta property="og:description"  content="description" />
```

but it doesn't work on mobile version.
Is there any suggestion how can I share images and urls on facebook?